# Threshold for boycotting companies

Tags: belief, business, freedom

At what point do Muslims have a moral and religious obligation to boycott a company. To clarify, most corporations or companies do things that are immoral. How do we decide what is bad enough that we boycott it?

Like for example, [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/e297c/trade_environment/wheeling/hnike.html) articles describes the Nike controversy, highlighting very bad working conditions for its workers. Would I be morally AND religiously obligated to boycott Nike?

I'm finding that my buying power is diminishing greatly with the possible boycotts I'm obligated to perform.

Answer (score 2):

Boycotting never works unless everyone is on the same page, which is never the case.

In Islam there is no such as boycotting, even from your enemies during war time.

> The Muslims are unanimously agreed that it is permissible to interact with ahl al-dhimmah (non-Muslims living under Muslim rule) and other kuffaar, so long as the object of the transaction is not haraam, but it is not permissible for a Muslim to sell weapons or tools of war to those who are waging war against the Muslims, or anything that helps them to support their religion.

Source: http://islamqa.info/en/20732

Feel free to buy from any company you want regardless of their political or religious standpoint, whom they support or what they believe in.

Comment: So, hypothetically, if there was a huge number of people boycotting Nike or some other company, then it would be proper to boycott it? Lastly, shouldn't we show effort at least? Perhaps Allah sees our effort, and makes it happen some way or another. Lastly,thanks for your response.

Comment: @Abdul No, you should never boycott (that was just a hypothetical I stated). Boycotting is never part of Islam because it never works/worked/etc.